# ventana que se desplace arriba hasta abajo y vuelva a sbuir en un lapso de tiempo

Tags: python-3.x

soy nuevo en python queria saber si puedo hacer esto  en tkinter python

hola amigos quiero en python realizar una ventana que se desplace   arriba hasta abajo  y vuelva  a sbuir   en un lapso de tiempo soy nuevo nose como hacerlo

Comment: Bueno, aqui no hacemos tutoriales. Pero si empiezas a hacerlo y te topas con un problema que no puedas resolver, nos cuentas.

Comment: Bienvenido! Es necesario que expongas el código en las preguntas y poner la traza de error que te surge en el código. Si no has llegado a este paso, es porque necesitas formarte y tomar investigación previa sobre el tema que estás tratando. Hay muchísima información, tutoriales, cursos, al respecto en Internet!